# Compare values in two input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input fields and i am wondering how do i compare value's between these two fields.

```
<input id="start" type="numeric" value="" />

        <input id="end" type="numeric" value="" />
```

In above input fields, if the value in input field with `id='start'` is greater than `id='end'`, i want to display an alert.

I tried below but not working

```
    if ($("#end").val()  > $("#start").val()) {

            //do something

    }else {
            alert('Wrong Input');
        }
```

What am i doing wrong???

Comment: `type="number"`, As per my knowledge there is type as such `numeric`

Comment: you are missing a closing `)` in the if statement

Comment: @Victory sorry typo mistake,but is correct in my code

Comment: When do you test the values? Is the code above part of a button or submit handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `type="number"`, As per my knowledge there is type as such `numeric`

*Code*

```
if (+$("#end").val() > +$("#start").val()) {
    //do something
} else {
    alert('Wrong Input');
}
```

Here I have use `+` to convert value to integer

Comment: @Richa, It happens with all of us.

Answer (score 4):

You should **bind an event handler such as '`keypress`'** to one of the fields. When that even is triggered, you should compare the values of both the input fields and show alert if necessary.

Additionally, `type="number"` is correct not `"numeric"` .

**Here's a working fiddle-**

http://jsfiddle.net/pe2ZE/

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing strings `$("#end").val()  > $("#start").val()` so you have to compare in numbers, and **dont forget about the radix**

```
if(parseInt($("#end").val(),10)  > parseInt($("#start").val(),10))
```

and `type="numeric"` is a wrong syntax, use `type="number"`

```
<input id="start" type="number" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `type="number"` to make the script work:

```
<input id="start" type="number" value="" />
<input id="end" type="number" value="" />
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eEJTs/)**

Or you can use input type text and then parse the input using `parseInt(val)` and compare them. somethink like this:

```
if (parseInt($("#end").val()) > parseInt($("#start").val())){
   //rest code
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot.Got it solved. That was some silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `type="numeric"` to make input numeric only

to solve this proplem use this code

HTML

`<input type="tel" name="name">`

jQuery

```
    // HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input
    $('[type=tel]').on('change', function(e) {
        $(e.target).val($(e.target).val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''))
    })
    $('[type=tel]').on('keypress', function(e) {
        keys = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','.']
        return keys.indexOf(event.key) > -1
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to type cast the value to int just like

```
if (parseInt($("#end").val())  > parseInt($("#start").val())) {

            //do something

    }else {
            alert('Wrong Input');
        }
```